# How do to connect Android Emulator to API/Swagger?

Tags: c#, flutter, swagger, emulation

I'm encountering a small issue with my Flutter app and I need assistance on how to resolve it. I've created a login screen and a home screen, along with the entire authorization and login functionality. The problem arises when attempting to connect the mobile app, running on an emulator, to my Swagger/API. The API functions perfectly, as the same API is utilized in the desktop version of the app without any issues. Here's an excerpt from my base provider code:

```
BaseProvider(String endpoint) {
    _baseUrl = const String.fromEnvironment("baseUrl", defaultValue: 
        "http://10.0.2.2:7166");
    if (!_baseUrl.endsWith("/")) {
        _baseUrl += "/";
    }

    _endpoint = endpoint;
    client.badCertificateCallback = (cert, host, port) => true;
    http = IOClient(client);
    fullUrl = "$_baseUrl$_endpoint";
}
```

As you can see, the `defaultValue` represents the default loopback address of the emulator and my port. However, this configuration isn't working. I'm starting to suspect that the issue might lie within the emulator itself. Specifically, I'm using the Pixel_3A_Api emulator. The app is being run on an emulator that is also launched from Visual Studio Code. Could it be necessary to configure proxy settings or adjust network settings? Do I need to establish a connection between my emulator and Wi-Fi (considering I'm using a cable on my PC)? Should I consider reinstalling the emulator? For the record, internet works on the emulator and on PC. It just seems like I can't connect to my API.

So far I have tried: reinstalling Android Studio, changing address, changing http to https, using `defaultValue: "https://localhost:7166/"` because this is the default value for desktop version of the app and it works flawlessly. I seriously have no clue how to fix this. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been trying to resolve this for a few days now without much success.

Comment: An emulator is a virtual machine with a different IP address.  So loopback will not run.  You need to find the IP of the virtual machine.  Than make sure there is a route using PING.  Once you get a route your code should work.

Comment: I think I found IP of the virtual machine, what do I do now? Replace the defaultValue with the one of the virtual machine and then add port: 7166? EDIT: Doesn't work.

Comment: Replace localhost with the IP.  You need a listener on the virtual machine and a route to the machine.  Check if PING works.

Comment: I did that, It does work and it does ping, I will try that and report on if it was successful.

Comment: Make sure you do not have two machines with the same IP.  Best way of checking is to PING before you create the Virtual machine.  If you get a response than you are not connecting to the virtual.